# Problem with paint job

Tags: paint

So I did a paint job on a 1985 ford pick up and It was my first time doing it, I sanded down the truck and primered it and then painted it like you should, after that I put 5 layers of clear coat on and I'm not satisfied with the result. The actual paint job looks good, but I cant see my reflection on it or anything. There is a slight shine to it, but thats it
Any tips

Comment: How was your flattening and buffing? There are questions about zhis in here already

Comment: first post a picture, it seems like you forgot to sand and buff the clear coat

Answer (score 1):

Try rubbing and/ or polishing compound. Rubbing compound is not as fine , however I used it alone with satisfactory results.  I use them with water but I have heard gasoline makes a better job.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the effects of weather : humidity , temperature, unless you are in a controlled environment - a garage is not controlled, a professional spray booth has humidity and temperature control as well as dust filtration and a baking facility...

Also, is the process you used : flatting and between coat preparation, a detailed explanation can be seen here : 
[Why did my clear coat turn out matte instead of glossy, and how can I fix it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/31570/why-did-my-clear-coat-turn-out-matte-instead-of-glossy-and-how-can-i-fix-it?rq=1)