# Should I put another coat of Meguiars cleaners wax on after I finish?

Tags: wax

For cleaners wax, should I put another coat of wax on after I finish?
Is there anything I should do to the wax after I finish?

Answer (score 1):

A second coat is of very limited benefit to be honest (and other waxes would struggle to adhere to the first coat in most cases) - It won't really look any different but may last slightly longer between coats. In my experience it's generally not worth the hassle in increased product usage and time spent for the minimal gains in longevity. Just keep an eye on how well water "beads" on the surface and once the droplets start getting noticeably bigger it's time to reapply.

The goal of something like Megs Cleaner Wax is to act as something of a "single step" product aimed at keeping things easy and quick for you to do so there isn't anything necessary afterwards. Depending on how even the coat was you can sometimes see benefits from giving it a quick once over with a quick detailler such as Megs "Last Touch" but it's not essential by any means. It does provide a great way to freshen the look of the vehicle inbetween waxings though and it does so without harming the existing wax coat (it's also a fantastic lubrication spray for use when claying!)

Is this the pick up you've sprayed [in this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48983/problem-with-paint-job)? If so cleaner wax probably isn't the right tool for the job - it won't hurt since it's non-abrasive but a more dedicated sealant like Dodo Juice Supernatural might be a better pick as you won't need the "cleaning" properties of the Cleaner Wax. It's more expensive but will give better optical clarity and it will last much longer between applications.